# Multiplying array doubles

Tags: objective-c, arrays, math, double

This code returns error  'Invalid operands to binary expressions double and double'

```
double staticDouble[3] = {1,2,3};
double dynamicDouble[3] = {a, b, c};
double resultTest = static * dynamic;
NSLog(@"%f",resultTest);
```

What I want this to do is to multiply 1 with a, 2 with b and 3 with c. abc are double values fetched from a textfield. How should I do this properly?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth How's this objc?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: The `@"%f`" is objective-C, I think?  It's certainly not standard C.  (Neither is a variable called `static`...)

Comment: Its obj-c from  xcode @OliCharlesworth i changed the real name from the code for readability. static was a name, not code. My bad

Comment: This is only Objective-C in the broadest sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `static` and `dynamic` are arrays, and there's no `*` operator for arrays; only for "arithmetic" types.  (Also, having an array named `static` is a problem, but I'm going to ignore that for the purposes of answering the question you actually asked).

Two options: compute the products one at a time:

```
double resultTest[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) resultTest[i] = static[i] * dynamic[i];
```

or call a library function that operates on vectors; for instance on iOS or OS X, you can do (you'll also need to link against the Accelerate framework):

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

...

double resultTest[3];
vDSP_vmul(static, 1, dynamic, 1, resultTest, 1, 3);
```

(This is slight overkill for arrays of size three; if you're going to be working exclusively with such small arrays, you may want to define your own functions or use a library that targets small fix-sized vector operations, like GLKit).

You'll run into the same problem printing the results; there's no format string to print the contents of an array, so you need to print the elements one at a time:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) NSLog(@"%f ", resultTest[i]);
```